# Logic off reading an xml file

Tags: c#, xml, list

I am reading an xml file in c#

it tkaes the structure of

```
<root>
<data>
    <file>
    <a>
    <b>
    <c>
</data>
<data>
    <file>
    <a>
    <b>
    <c>
</data>
</root>
```

and so on. I am reading through by getting a node list

`XmlNodeList listOfObjects = doc.SelectNodes("path")` and this gives me a list of nodes i can for each over. So each of these nodes represents 1 instance of the `<data>` tag, which has child nodes. I cant think of how i can foreach over the child nodes and add them to an arraylist.

If i have `List<Data> mylist = new List<Data>()` and inside there i want a file string a, string b, string c how in the xml foreach loop can i say

```
Data d = new Data(node.innertext, node.innertext.....)
mylist.add(d);
```

before anyone says i need to show code, i cant as its sensitive work data, i tried to make a decent example that shows the problem tho

thanks

Comment: If you can I would recommend switching to Linq-for-XML.  It's a much better model for working with xml in c# and you get the benefit of Linq as well.

Comment: Which framework version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Data
{
    string tagName;
    string value;
    public Data(string tagName, string value)
    {
        this.tagName = tagName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static List<Data> Parse(XmlNodeList nodes)
    {
        List<Data> listData = new List<Data>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                Data data = new Data(childNode.Name, childNode.InnerText);
                listData.Add(data);
            }
        }
        return listData;
    }
}
```

And then pass your node list as

```
List<Data> mylist = new List<Data>()
myList.AddRange(Data.Parse(yourNodelist));
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML example (runs in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) - set language to C# Program):

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = XElement.Parse(
        @"<root>
        <data>
            <file>file1</file>
            <a>nodea</a>
            <b>nodeb</b>
            <c>nodec</c>
        </data>
        <data>
            <file>file2</file>
            <a>node2a</a>
            <b>node2b</b>
            <c>node2c</c>
        </data>
        </root>");
    // Or use XElement.Load to load from file, stream, URI, etc.

    List<Data> mylist =
        doc.Elements()
            .Select(
                x =>
                new Data
                {
                    File = x.Element("file").Value,
                    A = x.Element("a").Value,
                    B = x.Element("b").Value,
                    C = x.Element("c").Value})  // or call constructor
            .ToList();

    mylist.Dump();  // LINQPad extension to display output
}

public class Data
{
    public string File { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is as rigid as you present it, don't foreach over the child nodes, but select the child nodes by name and extract the data.  You can do this with xpath if you like, but if  you can choose I'd go for linq-to-xml. It supports this scenario rather well. I had almost given up on xml until I discovered linq to xml.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to XML

```
XDocument algo = XDocument.Load("somefile");
List<Data> somelist = algo.Descendants("data").Elements().Select(x=> new Data(x)).ToList();
```

and Data is a personalized class that you could create to manage the content of that nodes.

```
class Data
{
    //possible properties to be set with "x"
    public Data(XElement x)
    {
        //Do something with x
    }
}
```